# kubernetes can't pull certain images from ibm cloud registry

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, container-registry

My pod does the following:

> Warning  Failed                 21m (x4 over 23m)     kubelet, 10.76.199.35  Failed to pull image "registryname/image:version1.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required

but other images will work. The output of

```
ibmcloud cr images
```

doesn't show anything different about the images that don't work. What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this is in kubenetes and you can see the image in `ibmcloud cr images` it most likely going to be a misconfiguration of your imagePullSecrets.

If you do `kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o yaml` you will be able to see the what `imagePullSecrets` are in scope for the pod and check if it looks correct (could be worth comparing it to a pod that is working).

It's worth noting that if your cluster is an instance in the IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service a default imagePullSecret for your account is added to the `default` namespace and therefore if you are running the pod in a different Kubenetes namespace you will need to do additional steps to make that work. This is a good place to start for information on this topic.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_images.html#other

Comment: This was exactly it. These steps also helped us:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_dedicated_tokens.html

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't logged into the IBM Cloud Container registry. If you haven't done this yet, You should login with this command

```
ibmcloud cr login
```

Other issues can be

- Docker is not installed.
- The Docker client is not logged in to IBM Cloud Container Registry.
- Your IBM Cloud access token might have expired.

You can find more troubleshooting instructions [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/ts_index.html#ts_pushpull)